# Java multiple inheritance design pattern?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have this structure:

`Class1`

Class2 extends Class1

I have a pile of utility classes on the side that take a Class2 to do all kinds of work.

The problem: I need to create a Class3 extending Class2 to use those classes. Class3 will have a Google API's Android MapView. MapViews can ONLY be created FROM A CLASS EXTENDING MapActivity. I would need

`Class3 extends Class2 AND MapActivity.`

which can't be done.

Changing my class3 to only extend MapActivity would require me to modify a hoard of code inherited (no pun intended) from previous developers.

Changing my class3 to only extend Class2 breaks because the map requires a MapActivity.

What would be the best approach?

EDIT: Several people mentioned the 'interface solution'. Sounds like the right solution. I forgot to mention, though, that Class2 is an *abstract* class, and it will be a pain to move the implemented methods around. A lot of code repetition... DRY goes wet on this one... :)

Comment: Does any class `Class1 to 3` extends `Activity'?

Comment: Nope... that's part of the problem

Comment: BTW, **Incredible** how fast you guys jumped on this one. I can't imagine how people programmed before stackoverflow... :)

Comment: Check this out for a solution to this problem. Found it after asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143220/multiple-inheritance-design-issue-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, you need to make a work around. If I was you I would make an interface that defines all of the things you need and then just extend your `Class1`

OR

You could simply make `Class1` extend `MapActivity` unless it already extends something else, but you would really only want to do this if `Class2` should extend `MapActivity`. Your `Class2` could extend `Class1` and your `Class3` could extend `Class1` and `Class1` could extend `MapActivity`.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, the most java-like solution to this problem is as follows.

1. Generally, try to use interfaces to define types which need to be extended.  For example, `JTable` uses the `TableModel` interface, which can be implemented from scratch, or by extending `AbstractTableModel` or `DefaultTableModel`
2. Understandably this is not always possible.  In your case, you can design `Class3` with a private field of type `Class1`.  Then implement as many wrapper methods as required to pass all incoming methods to the internal object.

Of course, (2) will give you all the behavior of `Class1`, but will not actually be an instance of `Class1`, which may break something else in your system.  Ans the answer to that problem is (again) to make greater use of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having class 3 extending MapActivity, why not try implementing it?
I had a very similar problem as yours and solved it by using implements.

Comment: Tried. The problem is that my Class1 extends LinearLayout and if you try "extends LinearLayout implements MapActivity" you get some clash between the classes (can't remember what clashed).

Comment: Note: THIS WOULD BE A GOOD SOLUTION IN OTHER CASES. (Just for reference)

Answer (score 0):

Can you create Class4 which extends MapActivity and use Class3 as a composition inside Class4.  Then you can delegate to apis of Class3. Obviously, this will work if dont need to access some internals of Class3 and above.

If you need access to the internals of Class3, then you can have Class5 extend Class3 to create apis which can help overcome that limitation of not having access to internals.

Answer (score 0):

yes Niall C.  is right .I am new to this but I khow that Java Doesn't support Mutliple Inheritance of Classes instead this You can create an interface that defines All the methods and members You want to use and Implement it.